# 2D matrix memory writing fail

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
char * define_row(int n)
{
    char * row=(char *)calloc(sizeof(char),n);
    row[0]='5';
    return row;

}


char ** define_matrix(int n,int m)
{
    char ** rows=(char **)calloc(sizeof(char),n);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i>0;i++)
    {
        rows[i]=define_row(m);
    }
    return rows;
}
void main()
{
    int n=5,m=5;
    char **k;
    k=define_matrix(n,m);
    printf("%d",&k[0][0]);

}
```

The code should allocate memory for a matrix NxM in size, but im testing it now for 5x5.
When running the code it does print a 0 like it should but when i add

```
void main()
{
    int n=5,m=5;
    char **k;
    k=define_matrix(n,m);
    k[0][0]=5;
    printf("%d",&k[0][0]);

}
```

it suddenly crashes mid run, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You should run this in the debugger, to determine which line caused the crash.

Comment: Any particular reason this was tagged as C++?

Comment: @0x499602D2 may be to attract both communitites?

Comment: You need to carefully read through your code and find other things. All of the problems found thus far have been by quick inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one issue. Your line:

```
char ** rows=(char **)calloc(sizeof(char),n);
```

should be:

```
char ** rows=(char **)calloc(sizeof(char*),n);
```

Because you stuffed addresses into array positions that you allocated 8-bit values for.

Comment: @Armin, yes true. I stopped reading after I saw the improper allocation. Once the for loop is fixed, he'll still have the calloc problem I pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that but it didnt help.

Answer (score 2):

First, of all:

```
for (i = 0; i > 0; i++)
```

looks strange. It could result in an undefined behavior because `i` will probably overflow.

You may rather write:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Moreover, you didn't allocate enough memory to use `rows[i]`. `sizeof(char)` is the size of one character (1 byte), but `rows[i]` is a pointer.

```
char **rows = calloc(sizeof(char), n);
```

Might become:

```
char **rows = calloc(sizeof *rows, n); /* ie sizeof(char *), n */
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop in `define_matrix` does not terminate.

You need to change

```
for(i=0;i>0;i++)
{
    rows[i]=define_row(m);
}
```

to

```
//------- use n instead of 0
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{
    rows[i]=define_row(m);
}
```

Comment: @0x499602D2, yeah just updated, thanks.